# Substr on sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, substr

This query:

```
SELECT substr(d.title,0,7)
FROM orders_total d, orders o
WHERE d.orders_id = o.orders_id
```

Gives me this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( d . title , '0' , '7' ) from orders_total d , orders o

It works without the substr, but I cannot get it to work with it.

Answer (score 2):

From [mySql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring):

> For all forms of SUBSTRING(), the position of the first character in
>   the string from which the substring is to be extracted is reckoned as
>   1.

So you have to change the 0 for 1:

```
SELECT substr(d.title,1,7)
FROM orders_total d, orders o
WHERE d.orders_id = o.orders_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LEFT(d.title,7) FROM orders_total d, orders o WHERE d.orders_id = o.orders_id
```

Answer (score 0):

sbustr should be substring, and it starts on index 1, not 0

Comment: as far as I know SUBSTR is a synonym for SUBSTRING